How to delete user from jenkins 2.426.3 using API method?
import jenkins.model.Jenkins  
import com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.rolestrategy.RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy

def jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()

def authStrategy = jenkins.getAuthorizationStrategy()

if (!(authStrategy instanceof RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy)) {
    println("The current authorization strategy is not Role-based. Please configure Jenkins to use Role-based Authorization Strategy.")
    return
}

def deleteUser(authStrategy, String type, String user) {
    try {
        authStrategy.doDeleteUser(type, user)
        println("Deleted the user '$user' successfully from type '$type'.")
    } catch (Exception e) {
        println("Failed to delete user '$user' from type '$type': ${e.message}")
    }
}

deleteUser(authStrategy, "globalRoles", "cleanup_test_user1")
jenkins.save()


I am using this, it says user deleted but user is not deleted on jenkins. Also, it says deleted even if user doesn't exist.
I am using this, it says user deleted but user is not deleted on jenkins. Also, it says deleted even if user doesn't exist.

Which "security realm" are you using? Security realm is like LDAP, Jetty or Jenkins own database. You can find that in the Manage Jenkins -> Security -> Authentication.

I am using Active Directory Security Realm and Role Based Authorization

yeah then this will not work. In Active Directory authentication jenkins doesnt hold any control. So this wont work. Because users are not controlled by jenkins at all.

So is there any method to delete users on my jenkins? If any user left the organization so can we delete that user from jenkins?

If i unassign roles to that user, then will it work?

If a user has left the organization then anyways it cannot login into the jenkins instance. As the active directory will reject the same.  Unassiging the roles to that user would work.
